# Locating kernel properties in Linux via C driver

Tags: c, linux, linux-kernel

so I'm doing research for my thesis but I've run into an issue. I'm using a driver my mentor has given me to analyze memory and extract features from a running process. The driver is written in C and I'm running it in Ubuntu 16.04 and the error I'm having is when I compile. My current kernel version is 4.10.0-42-generic.

The following are the three lines are giving an error because they are not found.

- (*task->active_mm).page_table_lock.rlock.raw_lock.tickets.head
- (*task->active_mm).shared_vm
- task->alloc_lock.rlock.raw_lock.tickets.head

For the first, the error starts on tickets I think. For the second shared_vm isn't found and for the last tickets is also where the error begins. My understanding is that the properties are no found.

I've been going through the kernel source files via https://elixir.free-electrons.com/linux/latest/source/kernel in the hopes of locating these properties but if anyone knows where they are or can help me locate them that would be very helpful. I'm new to all this so again any help is really appreciated.

Edit: The specific errors are: has no member named 'tickets', has no member named shared_vm, and has no member named 'tickets' for each respective line of code. Unfortunately I can't share any more code due to my professors request. [Screenshot of when I try to 'make'](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6ThNd.png)

Comment: What's the *exact* error message you are getting from the compiler?

Comment: You've told us there is an error on compiling, but have not stated the error, nor supplied any code from which the error originates.  Very hard to psychic debug this one.

Comment: "I've been going through the kernel source files via elixir.free-electrons.com/linux/latest/source/kernel in the hopes of locating these properties" - Why didn't you do that before asking the question? `struct arch_spinlock_t` [has no longer x86-specific specialization](http://elixir.free-electrons.com/linux/v4.10/ident/arch_spinlock_t‌​), and [uses generic specialization](http://elixir.free-electrons.com/linux/v4.10/source/include/asm-generic/qspinlock_types.h#L33) without `.tickets` field and its concepts. So, what do you want from us?

Comment: I've been doing that but haven't been getting anywhere so thought I'd ask cause I'm lost and new to this. I didn't realize tickets field and its concepts were no longer used.